# Pyramid traversal view lookup using method names

Tags: python, pyramid

In pyramid when using traversal url lookup, is it possible to have the view lookup algorithm check for method names of a class. For example, I could do something like this:

```
@view_defaults(context=models.Group)
class GroupView(object):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    @view_config(name='members')
    def members(self):
        pass
```

to match let's say */groups/somegroup/members*

Is there a way to make the name lookup part dynamic? That is, something like this:

```
@view_defaults(context=models.Group)
class GroupView(object):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    def members(self):
        pass

    def add(self):
        pass
```

So that both */groups/somegroup/members* and */groups/somegroup/add* will both resolve to their respective methods of the class?

Comment: You'll have to do this yourself. Don't forget that the view definitions are there not just to map the URL to a method but also to specify predicates and rendering options. You're going to lose all of that cool stuff on a per-view basis when you framework it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say this is the `best` way (I don't know anything about pyramid); but one option might be to just decorate the class with a decorator that decorates the method names appropriately.  eg.

```
import inspect

def config_wrap(func, name):
    @view_config(name=name)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

def dynamic_names(cls):
    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
        setattr(cls,name,config_wrap(m, name))
    return cls


@dynamic_names
@view_defaults(context=models.Group)
class GroupView(object):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    def members(self):
        pass

    def add(self):
        pass
```

Comment: knowing pyramid myself, this is the way I would go about it.

Comment: I thought about doing this, I was hoping there would be a built in way of doing it. Oh well, I'll probably go this route.